# How to make scalable web pages

Tags: html

I notice that pages like netflix.com and youtube.com display just as well on a 1024px iPad as they do on a 1900px monitor. In both cases all of the content is shown.  Nothing is ever cut off.

This implies that the HTML, or JavaScript, senses the screen width and then scales *everything* to that size.  If the native size is 1400px, for example, and the page is loaded into a 1024px screen, *everything* has to get scaled by 73%, including the fonts.

How do they do that?

Comment: A good starting point: check out literature on "Responsive web design".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), and the most common way to do it is by using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

So the page is not "scaled" per se, but designed to take advantage of the extra space and be usable despise the limitations of the consuming device.

Comment: Thank!  I found a half dozen books at Amazon on "Responsive Web Design."